# Applet not repeating loop

Tags: java, applet, switch-statement, do-while

**The Purpose:**

I have an assignment that involves a race between a tortoise and a hare. Basically, I have two .gif files, one of a tortoise and one of a hare, that are to be displayed in an applet and race each other by advancing along the x axis. In the process, I must use a random number generator to generate different "moves" in which the animal (image file) moves forward or backwards a certain number of positions. This loop must be repeated until one of the animals reach the 50th position. There also must be a time delay of some sort in between each move that the two animals make.

**The Code:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;

public class ProjectTwo extends Applet
{
    Image tortoise, hare;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int[] positions = new int [50];
    int[] randoms = new int[50];
    public int t = 0;
    public int h = 0;
    public int s = 0;

    public void init()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++)
        {
            positions[i] = ((i * 145) + 10);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < randoms.length; x++)
        {
            randoms[x] = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        }

        tortoise = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "images/tortoise.gif" );
        hare = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "images/hare.gif" );
    }

    public void delay()
    {
        for(int g = 0; g <= 90000000; g++) ;
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[0], 10, this);
        g.drawImage (hare, positions[0], 137, this);
        delay();delay();delay();

        do
        {
            switch (randoms[s])
            {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    t += 3;
                    h += 9;

                    if (t >= 50)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[50], 10, this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[t], 10, this);
                    }

                    if (h >= 50)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (hare, positions[50], 137, this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (hare, positions[h], 137, this);
                    }
                    s++;
                    break;

                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    t += 3;
                    h += 1;

                    if (t >= 50)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[50], 10, this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[t], 10, this);
                    }

                    if (h >= 50)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (hare, positions[50], 137, this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (hare, positions[h], 137, this);
                    }
                    s++;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    t += 1;
                    h -= -12;

                    if (t >= 50)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[50], 10, this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[t], 10, this);
                    }

                    if (h <= 0)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (hare, positions[0], 137, this);
                        t = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (hare, positions[h], 137, this);
                    }
                    s++;
                    break;

                case 7:
                case 8:
                    t += 1;
                    h -= 2;

                    if (t >= 50)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[50], 10, this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[t], 10, this);
                    }

                    if (h <= 0)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (hare, positions[0], 137, this);
                        t = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (hare, positions[h], 137, this);
                    }
                    s++;
                    break;

                case 9:
                case 10:
                    t -= 6;

                    if (t <= 0)
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[0], 10, this);
                        t = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.drawImage (tortoise, positions[t], 10, this);
                    }

                    g.drawImage (hare, positions[h], 137, this);
                    s++;
                    break;
            }
        } while (t >= 50 | h >= 50);
    }
}
```

**The Expected Result:**

- The tortoise.gif file appears at (10, 10) and the hare.gif file appears at (10, 137)
- There is a short delay until the random number generator rolls a 4 (It doesn't matter to me where/when the numbers are created as long as they are in between 1-10)
- The tortoise advances 3 positions (formula for positions is 145x + 10, making the tortoise's new coordinates (445, 10)
- The hare advances 1 position, making it's new coordinates (155, 10)
- Repeat process until one advances to the 50th position(see additional information for what should happen for every random number)

**What Actually Happens**

The tortoise and the hare show up in their appropriate places, but do not move.

**The Problem**

I want the tortoise and the hare to advance their positions according to a timer, but after compiling the code and launching the applet, due to some kind of mistake in my code, they do not.

**What I Think Might Be Wrong**

I believe the problem might have to do with how I implemented the delay, my using an element in an array as the x value for the images, or conflicting variables in my do-while loop and/or my case statement, although I do not know what is wrong nor what I should fix. However, I now realize that if the program does work, due to my use of randoms.length as a constructor in my for loop near the top, the tortoise and the hare will only change positions 50 times before stopping no matter what. I don't know how to fix this problem either.

**Additional Information**

- Here is a chart on how far the animals should move according to the random number chosen:

  > 1-2 = Tortoise moves +3 positions, Hare moves + 9
  >
  > 3-5 = Tortoise moves +3 positions, Hare moves +1
  >
  > 6 = Tortoise moves +1 position, Hare moves back -12
  >
  > 7-8 = Tortoise moves +1 position, Hare moves back -2
  >
  > 9-10 = Tortoise moves back -6 positions, Hare does not move at all
- An animal can move no farther back than the original position (positions[0]). If the number goes below, the animal must stay at that position. This rule also applies for positions greater than 50.
- This code compiles fine, but the applet doesn't function as attempted.
- I apologize if this code seems very messy, as I am fairly new to coding with Java as well as working with applets.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you should change

```
while (t >= 50 | h >= 50)
```

to

```
while (t <= 50 | h <= 50)
```

since t and h both start out at 0,and you want to loop while they are lower or equal to 50, not while they are higher or equal to 50.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I implemented it in my code, but the situation is the same, where the tortoise and the hare appear in the applet, but then they don't move.